# Joomla does not save field type editor value

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, tinymce, joomla3.0, codemirror

I have 3 types of editor in my Joomla website.

1. Editor - CodeMirror
2. Editor - None (shows simple textarea)
3. Editor - TinyMCE

My question is that, except the "Editor - None" all other editor does not saves the value in a database. Actually, it doest not Post data from Editor field to jquery ajaxsubmit function which serialise all the data except editor field.

Note : If I click on "Toggle Editor" button & goes to save then it works otherwise it doesn't.

[image]

XML Code :

```
<field name="application-form_Portfolio" type="editor" label="Portfolio" description="" class="" buttons="1" rows="400" cols="400" filter="safehtml"/>
```

Javascript file :

http://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js

Is there any generic solution for it.

Comment: Actually, the hidden textarea field for editor does not get replaced/filled as a value of editor content..

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Joomla developer, but are you making sure that your posting method has access to the content of TinyMCE, and not just the editor elements itself?